# Determine if $x is divisible evenly by $y in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point, modulus

I simply want to know if $x is evenly divisible by $y.  For example's sake assume:

```
$x = 70;
$y = .1;
```

First thing I tried is:

```
$x % $y
```

This seems to work when both numbers are integers but fails if they are not and if `$y` is a decimal less than 1 returns a "Division by zero" error, so then I tried:

```
fmod($x,$y)
```

Which returns equally confusing results, "0.099999999999996".

php.net states `fmod()`:

> Returns the floating point remainder of dividing the dividend (x) by the divisor (y)

Well according to my calculator `70 / .1 = 700`.  Which means the remainder is 0.  Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not all values have an exact float-point representation: it's thus not "[perfectly] evenly" (except in the case of integers) so much as "close enough".

Comment: [This happens with bcmod(), too.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ztb1Y2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution would be doing a normal *division* and then comparing the value to the next integer. If the result is that integer or very near to that integer the result is evenly divisible:

```
$x = 70;
$y = .1;

$evenlyDivisable = abs(($x / $y) - round($x / $y, 0)) < 0.0001;
```

This subtracts both numbers and checks that the absolute difference is smaller than a certain rounding error. This is the usual way to compare floating point numbers, as depending on how you got a float the representation may vary:

```
php> 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3
bool(false)
php> serialize(.3)
'd:0.29999999999999999;'
php> serialize(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1)
'd:0.30000000000000004;'
```

---

See this demo:

```
php> $x = 10;
int(10)
php> $y = .1;
double(0.1)
php> abs(($x / $y) - round($x / $y, 0)) < 0.0001;
bool(true)
php> $y = .15;
double(0.15)
php> abs(($x / $y) - round($x / $y, 0)) < 0.0001;
bool(false)
```

Comment: I'm interested in this solution.  One question, why use subtraction and `< 0.0001` instead of simply `($x / $y) == round($x / $y)`?

Comment: @billynoah I amended my answer, explaining why floats should be compared like this.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I think I understand, but in what scenario would the method I suggested in the comment above return different result than yours?

Comment: For what bounds and/or constraints on `$x` and `$y` is this guaranteed to return a correct answer?

Comment: @billynoah `$x = .3`, `$y = .1`. But it is always better to be safe than sorry!

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's going to fail when the division results in a number that is larger than `PHP_INT_MAX`. This causes PHP to convert it to floating point and lose precision. For example `$x = 8000000000000000000` and `$y = 0.0015` on my 64 bit PHP.

Comment: I'm actually more confused than ever about doing this with .3 and .1.  `$x/$y = 3` and `round($x/$y) = 3` but `($x/$y) - round($x/$y) =
-4.4408920985006E-16` ???  Why is this so difficult?  obviously .3 / .1 is a whole number but it doesn't work.

Comment: @billynoah This probably warrants an own question, as comments are not suitable for answering these things.

Comment: @billynoah It works fine if you compare the absolute value of the result against a small enough floating number — as I said in the answer.

Comment: @TimWolla: Clearly the test produces a wrong answer for `$x = 1.2345`, `$y = 1.2344`, since the test indicates true, but 1.2345 is not evenly divisible by 1.2344. What criteria would guarantee the test produces a correct answer?

Comment: @Eric - I could be wrong but I think this is as simple as adding another 0 to the comparison, i.e., `< 0.00001` should do it since your numbers have four decimal places.  Seems like there should be a way to easily do this for _any_ number but i've yet to find a better solution than this.

Comment: @billynoah: That fixes one case but does not describe when this tests works and when it does not. This should be considered a serious problem in software: You have some code that appears to work, sort of, but it is known to break sometimes, and you do not know when it breaks and when it works.

Answer (score 6):

.1 doesn't have an exact representation in binary floating point, which is what causes your incorrect result. You could multiply them by a large enough power of 10 so they are integers, then use %, then convert back. This relies on them not being different by a big enough factor that multiplying by the power of 10 causes one of them to overflow/lose precision. Like so:

```
$x = 70;
$y = .1;
$factor = 1.0;
while($y*$factor != (int)($y*$factor)){$factor*=10;}
echo ($x*$factor), "\n";
echo ($y*$factor), "\n";
echo (double)(($x*$factor) % ($y*$factor))/$factor;
```

Comment: The numbers are based on user input in a form.  They could be anything numeric.

Comment: I fixed it so that the only int based size limitation is the final size of y, rather than the difference between x and y. The allowable difference is only bounded by the limitations of floats.

Comment: +1 for ".1 doesn't have an exact representation in binary floating point" (See the Patriot bug: http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~alum/patriot_bug.html)

Answer (score 4):

There is a pure math library in bitbucket : https://bitbucket.org/zdenekdrahos/bn-php

The solution will be then :

```
php > require_once 'bn-php/autoload.php';
php > $eval = new \BN\Expression\ExpressionEvaluator();
php > $operators = new \BN\Expression\OperatorsFactory();
php > $eval->setOperators($operators->getOperators(array('%')));
php > echo $eval->evaluate('70 % 0.1'); // 0
0.00000000000000000000
```

**tested on php5.3**

credits : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmod.php#111276

Answer (score 0):

Float-point representation varies from machine to machine. Thankfully there are standards. PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format for floating-point representation which is one of the most common standards. [See here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) for more information on that. With that said take a look at [this calculator](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/) for a better understanding as to the **why**. As for the **how** I like Tim's solution especially if you're dealing with user input.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, using the modulus operator works fine when it's an integer, so why not set it up so that it operates on integers. In my case, I needed to check divisibility by 0.25:

```
$input = 5.251
$x = round($input, 3); // round in case $input had more decimal places
$y = .25;
$result = ($x * 1000) % ($y * 1000);
```

In your case:

```
$input = 70.12
$x = round($input, 2);
$y = .1;
$result = ($x * 100) % ($y * 100);
```